# Overflowing UI Layout

Tags: android

I have an application that uses a custom dropdown style interface. For reasons that are somewhat complicated to explain, I have to go with this instead of the built in Android Spinner.

I'm running into a problem getting the dropdown options (orange) to overlap the dialog (green) that I'm opening. fill_parent makes the green section much too large when the dropdown isn't open, and setting it too small leaves a black area behind the green dialog area, the same size as when it's fill parent.

Is there a way to acheive this type of layout?

[image]

Instead it's showing up like this:
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vw_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_stacker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_prompt_message"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="10dip"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_dropdown_closed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_question"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="@string/request_control_dropdown_option_1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/background_dropdown"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_dropdown_closed">

            <trioro.voyeur.ui.GhostButton
                android:id="@+id/gb_yes"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_yes"/>

            <trioro.voyeur.ui.GhostButton
                android:id="@+id/gb_no"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_no" />

        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_dropdown_open"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_question"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="1dip"
            android:paddingLeft="1dip"
            android:paddingRight="1dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dropdown_option_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/request_control_dropdown_option_1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dropdown_option_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/request_control_dropdown_option_2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dropdown_option_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/request_control_dropdown_option_3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dropdown_option_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/request_control_dropdown_option_4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the image what is happening, or what you want to happen?

Comment: What I would like to happen. I've added some markup and an image for what is happening

Answer (score 2):

Try using `LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL` for your popup list windows.
Sorry, I can't be more specific without seeing actual code.